# How to find elements that start with a sub strings inside a sorted ArrayList?

Tags: java, search, arraylist

I have a sorted arrayList of 33000 elements using java, how can I list only the elements that start with a substring.

For example:
I have a string "air". So I need every word that starts with "air" ("airplane", "airforce", "airline", etc.)

Is there a way to do that without iterating one by one?

Comment: Yes there are multiple ways. What have you tried so far ?

Comment: If the list isn't sorted, then it will involve iterating over the whole list!

Comment: For loop with regex pattern, but I´m using it inside another loop. So is doing the big search for every loop...

Comment: the ArrayList is sorted

Comment: Then binary search the insertion index of your prefix, and go from there.

Comment: May be Guava's BoolFilter may help you to solve efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

How about [Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html)?

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("airplane", "airforce", "airline", "etc.");
List<String> prefixWords = list.stream()
            .filter(word -> word.startsWith("air"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

prefixWords.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: This is the simplest solution with java 8.

Answer (score 1):

So, given you have a sorted `ArrayList<String>` `words`, you can do:

```
String prefix = "air";
int start = Collections.binarySearch(words, prefix);  
// index of prefix OR -(insertion point) - 1
if (start < 0)  // prefix is not contained as a whole word
    start = -start - 1;
int end = start;
while (end < words.size() && words.get(end).startsWith(prefix))
    end++;
List<String> prefixWords = words.subList(start, end);
```

The binary search is `O(log(N))` and the slicing is `O(K)` where  `K` is the length of the sublist (number of "air"-prefixed words). So, this should be much better than iterating over the list, at least ammortized over different prefixes (worst case being that all words start with prefix).

Comment: what is end? is the end index of my arrayList?

Comment: Updated it. `end` is the end index (exclusive) of the sublist.

Answer (score 1):

Binary search would be first goto like

```
    public static int binarySearch(ArrayList<String> sortedArray,String find){
        int lowerBound=0;
        int upperBound=sortedArray.size()-1;

        while(true){
            int midIndex=lowerBound+((upperBound-lowerBound)/2);
            String curr=sortedArray.get(midIndex);
            if(upperBound<lowerBound){
                System.out.println("word not found");
                return -1;
            }

            if (curr.equals(find))
                return midIndex;

            if(curr.compareTo(find)>0)
                upperBound=midIndex-1;

            if(curr.compareTo(find)<0)
                lowerBound=midIndex+1;
        }
    }
```

Then after you got index iterate over the list towards the left and right until either you hit end of list/beginning or a prefix different from the one youre searching for

```
       public static ArrayList<String> makeList(ArrayList<String> sortedArray,String startingWith){
        ArrayList<String> result=new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> temp=new ArrayList<>(sortedArray.size());            

        for(int i=0;i<sortedArray.size();i++){
            temp.add(" ");
        }

        //copy sortedArray to temp
        for(String s: sortedArray){
            if(s.length()>startingWith.length()) {
                temp.set(sortedArray.indexOf(s), s.substring(0, startingWith.length()));
            } else temp.set(sortedArray.indexOf(s),s);

        }


        int index=binarySearch(temp,startingWith);
        result.add(sortedArray.get(index));

        int leftIndex=index;
        int rightIndex=index;         
        while(true){

            //if left and right index dont go out of bounds cont. iterating
            if ((leftIndex - 1) >= 0) leftIndex--;
            if ((rightIndex + 1) < sortedArray.size()) rightIndex++;

            //if left and right index are at end of list return
            if( (rightIndex>=sortedArray.size()) && (leftIndex<0) ) return result;

            boolean isLeft;
            boolean isRight;

            if( sortedArray.get(leftIndex).length()>startingWith.length() ) {
                isLeft = sortedArray.get(leftIndex).substring(0,startingWith.length()).equals(startingWith);
            }else isLeft=false;


            if( sortedArray.get(rightIndex).length()>startingWith.length() ) {
                isRight = sortedArray.get(rightIndex).substring(0,startingWith.length()).equals(startingWith);
            }else isRight=false;

            if(!isLeft && !isRight) return result;


            if( isRight ) result.add(sortedArray.get(rightIndex));
            if( isLeft ) result.add(sortedArray.get(leftIndex));

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't know the number of elements that starts with "air" before hand your search will be at the order of O(n). there is no brute force method or balance tree search you can perform to achieve this in less than O(n).